# Android playstore sqlite onupgrade not called

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I am facing a problem where `SQLiteOpenHelper`OnUpgrade is not being called.

I have increased the database version as well prior was 1 or 2 which I dont recall and I have set it to 100.

If I change the database version from 2 to 100, its calling the onUpgrade provided that I am debugging // running the Android project on my machine.

*The same I download from playstore and then on my project i change the version from 2 to 100. Install the new version of the app on the device where the existing old playtsore version is installed, the onUpgrade is not called.*

I have called explicitly the

> DatabaseHelper  dbHelper = new
>   DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
>
> SQLiteDatabase sqlite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Any help please its been hours I am sitting with it but not working.